# only partial text change on hover over button

Tags: css, button, hover, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like the font-color of the text in the button change into white and without the underline when hovering over the button.

At the moment the text color only changes when you're hovering on the text itself and not yet when hovering over the button. So when you move over the button the text stays black, until you move over the text.

Here you can find the [css here](http://jsfiddle.net/yKvRw/)

HTML:

```
<a><button class="btn-free-trial btn-xs">free trial</a>
```

CSS:

```
button.btn-free-trial {
    background-color: #FBFAFA;
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: #FB684C;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

button.btn-free-trial:hover {
    background-color: #FB684C;
    color: #FFF;
}

button.btn-free-trial a {
    color: #3C3735;
}

button.btn-free-trial a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you forgot to close the ending tag for button `</button>`.

```
<a><button class="btn-free-trial btn-xs">free trial</button></a>
```

Secondly you don't need to use both `<a>` and `<button>`,

```
<button class="btn-free-trial btn-xs">free trial</button>
<a class="btn-free-trial btn-xs">free trial</a>
```

Check this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yKvRw/11/

Answer (score 0):

you forget to close the button tag

```
<a><button class="btn-free-trial btn-xs">free trial</button></a>
```

after doing this the button hover will display correctly

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your fiddle there are some essential changes that I found important. Those are:

1. You are using button inside a tag which is a logically wrong method. Either use a tag with `href="#link"` or button if you want to call any action in it.
2. Try to close tag first as soon as you create a tag and then write a content inside it. This will avoid mistakes like forgetting a closing tag.
3. If you are confident about your coding logic but cannot find a syntactical mistake like forgetting closing tag then validate your code on W3C Validator. This will make you syntactically perfect. Here is the link:

https://validator.w3.org/